# Add Dropdownlist control into column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I need to add an extra row in the `GridView` and add `DropDownList` controls in each column.

I am using `DataTable`, so I added a row:

```
DropDownList visitorData = new DropDownList();

DataRow myNewRow;

myNewRow = contacts.NewRow();
myNewRow["Source"] = "here should be my dropdownlist";
contacts.Rows.InsertAt(myNewRow, 0);
```

How do I add a `DropDownList` control instead of text into each column?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that you are dynamically creating the DropDownLists instead of placing them inline inside of the GridView?

Comment: Are you trying to add the data/text from the dropdownlist or are you trying to add the control itself?

Comment: no reason, but how do I dynamically add a row with dropdownlist without using code behind?

Comment: I guess that you need a "Filter" functionality (like Excel). In this case I recommend you to find some third-party UI component (i.e. telerik)

Answer (score 0):

Place them in the [GridView.FooterTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.footertemplate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

> Use the FooterTemplate property to
>   specify the custom content displayed
>   in the footer section of a
>   TemplateField object. Define the
>   content by creating a template that
>   specifies how the footer section is
>   rendered.
>
> To specify a template, first place
>   opening and closing 
>   tags between the opening and closing
>   tags of the  element.
>   Next, add the custom content between
>   the opening and closing
>    tags. The content can
>   be as simple as plain text or more
>   complex (embedding other controls in
>   the template, for example).